# Node exporter and kubectl top seem to reporting different values for memory utilization?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, heapster

I am using this query to calculate memory utilization of a node

```sh
 (1 - node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{cluster="$cluster"}/node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{cluster="$cluster"}) * 100
```

I see values around 25%

but when I run `kubectl top node` for the same node I see a value around 16%

Comment: Are the values consistent over time? Where you able to correlate the exact time on the query with when you ran `kubectl top node`?

Comment: no , they are always off

Comment: @user2062360 Could you please share the actual output of `kubectl top node'?

Answer (score 2):

The difference in values between `kubectl top node` and Prometheus's node exporter values comes from the way these data is being collected and calculated.

When you execute `kubectl top node` Kubernetes reads values from root cgroup. Specifically from `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes` and
`/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat`. The total memory usage is being calculated as: `memory.usage_in_bytes` - `total_inactive_file`.

However, Prometheus's node exporter reads values from `/proc/meminfo` and than calculates it according to your query which seems correct.

This difference is also being discussed in this (still open) [issue](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/2042).

One way of dealing with it would be to simply stick to one method of measurement and reporting.